# How to check whether a JPEG image is color or gray scale using only Python stdlib

Tags: python, image-processing, python-2.6

I have to write a test case in Python to check whether a jpg image is in color or grayscale. Can anyone please let me know if there is any way to do it with out installing extra libraries like OpenCV?

Comment: Questions: a) What libraries are not considered extra libraries? NumPy/Scipy? b) Do you want to simply detect 2 vs 3 channels and use this as your grayscale criteria or will you have 3 channel images that are actually grayscale in appearance?

Comment: We have only python 2.6 on our linux work stations. There are strict instructions to not use any external libraries to write any of the test cases. So we don't have permissions to install any libraries. We have some 3 channel images that are actually grayscale in appearance.

Comment: Do you have *any* way of opening an image as pixels? If not this is going to be a hard problem.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: you mean you can't just trust the JPEG header, offset 6: number of components (1 = grayscale, 3 = RGB) ?

Comment: @smci I guess grayscale JPEGs are so rare that I didn't remember it was possible. There will also be cases where a grayscale image is saved with 3 components.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check every pixel to see if it is grayscale (R == G == B)

```
from PIL import Image

def is_grey_scale(img_path):
    img = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
    w, h = img.size
    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(h):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel((i,j))
            if r != g != b: 
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: Just a performance-enhance for fast results: since many images have black or white border, you'd expect faster termination by sampling random i,j-points from `im` and test them? Or use modulo arithmetic to traverse the image. If sampling(-without-replacement) say 100 random i,j-points isn't conclusive, then just scan it linearly. Or maybe vary the row order with modulo arithmetic. You could wrap all this in a custom iterator `iter_pixels(im)`.

Comment: Sorry. The code is failing when I tried to run the script and it is giving the error @ r,g,b = im.getpixel((i,j))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Need to add rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

Comment: @kadina if it opens and isn't RGB then you already have your answer - I believe the only other possibility is grayscale. At least for a JPEG.

Comment: @MarkRansom, JPEGs are stored in either CMYK, Greyscale, or YUV (with YUV almost always converted to RGB by the parser).

Comment: @rsaxvc by the time the image is opened by most libraries the distinction is lost.

Comment: You can even increase the speed by skipping some pixels such as `for i in range(0, w, 2)` and `for j in range(0, h, 2)`

Answer (score 31):

Can be done as follow:

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave, imresize
image = imread(f_name)
if(len(image.shape)<3):
      print 'gray'
elif len(image.shape)==3:
      print 'Color(RGB)'
else:
      print 'others'
```

Comment: Effective answer. Whether an image is RGB or gray can be determined by its size.

Comment: Please note that the 3-channel image can also be a grayscale image. This answer is applied to a 2-channel grayscale image only.

Comment: @FonyLew what do you mean by that? RGB image has 3 channels, grayscale image has 1 channel.

Comment: @orbit It's in an ideal case. However, there can be a greyscale image with the 3-channel image (RGB) where R == G == B as mentioned in other comments. The output is visually the same as a grey image, but it is RGB in metadata where this answer doesn't apply to that case. I meant to say that the answer is only counted as greyscale when the number of channels is less than three.

Answer (score 22):

There is more pythonic way using numpy functionality and opencv:

```
import cv2
def isgray(imgpath):
    img = cv2.imread(imgpath)
    if len(img.shape) < 3: return True
    if img.shape[2]  == 1: return True
    b,g,r = img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,2]
    if (b==g).all() and (b==r).all(): return True
    return False
```

Comment: I like this approach.  However, note that your code doesn't actually use OpenCV functions in its logic. OpenCV is only used to load the image from file.

Answer (score 19):

For faster processing, it is better to avoid loops on every pixel, using ImageChops, (but also to be sure that the image is truly grayscale, we need to compare colors on every pixel and cannot just use the sum):

```
from PIL import Image,ImageChops

def is_greyscale(im):
    """
    Check if image is monochrome (1 channel or 3 identical channels)
    """
    if im.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
        raise ValueError("Unsuported image mode")

    if im.mode == "RGB":
        rgb = im.split()
        if ImageChops.difference(rgb[0],rgb[1]).getextrema()[1]!=0: 
            return False
        if ImageChops.difference(rgb[0],rgb[2]).getextrema()[1]!=0: 
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 6):

In case of a grayscale image, all channels in a certain pixel are equal (if you only have one channel, then you don't have a problem).
So basically, you can list all the pixels with their three channel values to check if each pixel has all three channels equal.

`Image.getcolors()` returns an unsorted list of (count, pixel) values.

```
im = Image.open('path_to_image.whatever')
color_count = im.getcolors()
```

If `len(color_count)` exceeds 256 (default max value), this function returns None, meaning you had more than 256 color options in your pixel list, hence it is a colored image (grayscale can only have 256 colors, `(0,0,0)` to `(255,255,255)`).

So after that you only need :

```
if color_count: 
    # your image is grayscale
else:
    # your images is colored
```

Note this will work only when using the default parameter value of `getcolors()`.

Documentation: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors

Comment: I tested this on a grayscale image (single-channel), an image with color (with and without transparency), and an image without color (converted to black/white mode in Photoshop, with and without transparency). All tests produced the expected result. I don't understand why this isn't the accepted answer. This is the simplest and cleanest approach of all the answers, and it works reliably!

Answer (score 5):

A performance-enhance for fast results: since many images have black or white border, you'd expect faster termination by sampling a few random i,j-points from im and test them? Or use modulo arithmetic to traverse the image rows. First we sample(-without-replacement) say 100 random i,j-points; in the unlikely event that isn't conclusive, then we scan it linearly.

Using a custom iterator iterpixels(im). I don't have PIL installed so I can't test this, here's the outline:

```
import Image

def isColor(r,g,b): # use tuple-unpacking to unpack pixel -> r,g,b
    return (r != g != b)

class Image_(Image):
    def __init__(pathname):
        self.im = Image.open(pathname)
        self.w, self.h = self.im.size
    def iterpixels(nrand=100, randseed=None):
        if randseed:
            random.seed(randseed) # For deterministic behavior in test
        # First, generate a few random pixels from entire image
        for randpix in random.choice(im, n_rand)
            yield randpix
        # Now traverse entire image (yes we will unwantedly revisit the nrand points once)
        #for pixel in im.getpixel(...): # you could traverse rows linearly, or modulo (say) (im.height * 2./3) -1
        #    yield pixel

    def is_grey_scale(img_path="lena.jpg"):
        im = Image_.(img_path)
        return (any(isColor(*pixel)) for pixel in im.iterpixels())
```

(Also my original remark stands, first you check the JPEG header, offset 6: number of components (1 = grayscale, 3 = RGB). If it's 1=grayscale, you know the answer already without needing to inspect individual pixels.)

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar situation, where I tried the following approaches:

1. Reading using `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`and checking for image.shape
2. Splitting B,G,R channels and checking if they are equal

Both of these approaches got me only like 53% accuracy in my dataset.
I had to relax the condition for checking pixels in different channels and create a ratio to classify it as grey or color. With this approach, I was able to get 87.3% accuracy on my dataset.

Here is the logic which worked for me:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

###test image
img=cv2.imread('test.jpg')

### splitting b,g,r channels
b,g,r=cv2.split(img)

### getting differences between (b,g), (r,g), (b,r) channel pixels
r_g=np.count_nonzero(abs(r-g))
r_b=np.count_nonzero(abs(r-b))
g_b=np.count_nonzero(abs(g-b))

### sum of differences
diff_sum=float(r_g+r_b+g_b)

### finding ratio of diff_sum with respect to size of image
ratio=diff_sum/img.size

if ratio>0.005:
    print("image is color")
else:
    print("image is greyscale")
```

Comment: This error is showing after using this code  `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)`

Comment: check if the image path was given correctly. After `img=cv2.imread('path/to/image.jpg')` do a `print(img.shape)` and what is the output.

Comment: abs not needed, only two differences needed

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't we use ImageStat module?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageStat

def is_grayscale(path="image.jpg")

    im = Image.open(path).convert("RGB")
    stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)

    if sum(stat.sum)/3 == stat.sum[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**stat.sum** gives us a sum of all pixels in list view = [R, G, B] for example [568283302.0, 565746890.0, 559724236.0]. For grayscale image all elements of list are equal.

Comment: an image composed of an equal number of pure red, pure green and pure blue pixels would wrongly identify as greyscale

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I needed a different solution.
Sometimes 3 channel images (eg RGB) might be almost grayscale without every pixel being identical in 3 channels. This checks every pixel but you can also subsample the image if needed. I used slope here but you can use checks on most of these parmaters from the regression. Linear regressions are usually very fast due to internal matrix multiply solution.

```
import glob
import scipy
import cv2
THRESH = 0.01
BASEDIR = 'folder/*.jpg'

files = glob.glob(BASEDIR)
for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    slope1, intercept1, r1, p1, se1 = scipy.stats.linregress(img[:,:,0].flatten(),img[:,:,1].flatten())
    slope2, intercept2, r2, p2, se2 = scipy.stats.linregress(img[:,:,0].flatten(),img[:,:,2].flatten())
    if abs(slope1 - 1) > THRESH or abs(slope2 - 1) > THRESH:
        print(f'{file} is colour')
    else:
        print(f'{file} is close to grey scale')
```

Comment: This approach is interesting and it can be improved considering https://stackoverflow.com/a/2333251/694360, but I think it has a weakness due to the fact that, for some color images (very far from grayscale), colors might fit very close to a grayscale image. Just think of an image made of the 3 pixels `(0,255,255)`, `(255,0,255)` and `(255,255,0)`; if I understand your code, it would be detected as perfect grayscale, but it's not. Anyway a vote up for considering the *almost grayscale* topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of Alexey Antonenko answer using PIL.image instead of cv2. In case you have float images I think it is safer to use the `np.allclose` function.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
def isgray(imgpath):
    img_pil = Image.open(imgpath)
    img = np.asarray(img_pil)
    if len(img.shape) < 3: return True
    if img.shape[2]  == 1: return True
    r,g,b = img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,2]
    if np.allclose(r,g) and np.allclose(r,b): return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be done as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('f_name',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
if(len(image.shape)<3):
  if(len(np.unique(image)) == 2):
    print('Binary Image')
  else:
    print('gray')
elif(len(image.shape))==3:
  print('Color(RGB)')
else:
  print('others')
```

Answer (score -3):

As you are probably correct, OpenCV may be an overkill for this task but it should be okay to use Python Image Library (PIL) for this. The following should work for you:

```
import Image
im = Image.open("lena.jpg")
```

**EDIT**
As pointed out by Mark and JRicardo000, you may iterate over each pixel. You could also make use of the im.split() function here.

Comment: The mode is always going to be RGB from a JPEG. You need to actually examine the pixels.