# How to test if a JPEG is RGB or CYMK in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jpeg

I look after a PIL solution but I could find any glue to that.

There's a lot of options to convert to RGB but I didn't find any who just indicates which color format were decoded.

I found a C library but I don't know if it can be used with python:

http://www.openjpeg.org/

Comment: Have you checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660929/how-to-check-whether-a-jpeg-image-is-color-or-gray-scale-using-only-python-stdli)?

Comment: ```from PIL import Image : image = Image.open(path_to_image) : print(image.mode) ```

Comment: Yes Muhammad. But it was not clear that testing grayscale has relation to RGB or CYMK.