# How to reference an image without writing in Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-3.7, opencv

This is the code that I currently have. I want to avoid writing an image then loading it again and then copying it. Why isn't my code in the second part working?

```
import cv2

load_imaged = cv2.imread("image.png", 0)

# Apply GaussianBlur to reduce image noise if it is required
otsu_threshold, otsu_result = cv2.threshold(
    load_imaged, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU, )
# Optimal threshold value is determined automatically.

# Visualize the image after the Otsu's method application
cv2.imwrite("otsu.png", otsu_result)

hole_image = cv2.imread("otsu.png")

# copy image
img = hole_image.copy()
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("Image", imgray)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and I'm trying to reference the image like this **(in line 9)** but it's returning an error.

> Invalid number of channels in input image:
> 'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
> 'scn' is 1

```
import cv2

load_imaged = cv2.imread("image.png", 0)

# Apply GaussianBlur to reduce image noise if it is required
otsu_threshold, otsu_result = cv2.threshold(
    load_imaged, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU, )
# copy image
img = otsu_result.copy()
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("Image", imgray)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert an gray-scale image into gray image.

Remove `imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` line and you will get the result.

Comment: That was a simple fix! Of course. I didn't think it would have been a problem. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to check the shape of the image. (if gray-scale shape is `width, height`, if rgb `width, height, 3`). Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660929/how-to-check-whether-a-jpeg-image-is-color-or-gray-scale-using-only-python-stdli)