# How to check whether a jpeg image is color or grayscale using only Python PIL? (not using OpenCV)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62915019/13401838) really helpful and it's actually working quite accurately. BUT this uses OpenCV.. and I want to use the same method using PIL.

code using PIL instead of OpenCV:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

###test image
img=Image.open('')
img=img.load()

### splitting b,g,r channels
r,g,b=img.split()

### getting differences between (b,g), (r,g), (b,r) channel pixels
r_g=np.count_nonzero(abs(r-g))
r_b=np.count_nonzero(abs(r-b))
g_b=np.count_nonzero(abs(g-b))

### sum of differences
diff_sum=float(r_g+r_b+g_b)

### finding ratio of diff_sum with respect to size of image
ratio=diff_sum/img.size

if ratio>0.005:
    print("image is color")
else:
    print("image is greyscale")
```

I changed `cv2.imread('')` to `Image.open('')` and added `img=img.load()`.
and I changed `b,g,r=cv2.split(img)` to `r,g,b=img.split()`

I know that `split()` method exists in PIL. but I'm having this error.

```
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I don't have any grayscale JPEGs handy to test this, but I would assume that the `mode` attribute of the loaded image would be `"L"` instead of `"RGB"`.  (This assumes that it's truly a grayscale file, and not merely RGB with R==G==B.)

Comment: oh I checked the mode of all the images long time ago, and they were all RGB :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `data types` like you are [mixing Red Bull and Vodka](https://www.scinapse.io/papers/2046017245).
The `load` method is producing the error because it converts the `PIL` image into a `PixelAccess` object, an you need a `PIL` image for `split()`. Also, `count_nonzero()` does not work because it operates on `NumPy` arrays, and you are attempting to call that method on a `PIL` image. Lastly, `size` returns a *tuple* (`width` and `height`) of the image, so you need to modify your code accordingly:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

###test image
img=Image.open("D://opencvImages//lena512.png")

### splitting b,g,r channels
r,g,b=img.split()

### PIL to numpy conversion:
r = np.array(r)
g = np.array(g)
b = np.array(b)

### getting differences between (b,g), (r,g), (b,r) channel pixels
r_g=np.count_nonzero(abs(r-g))
r_b=np.count_nonzero(abs(r-b))
g_b=np.count_nonzero(abs(g-b))

### sum of differences
diff_sum=float(r_g+r_b+g_b)

### get image size:
width, height = img.size

### get total pixels on image:
totalPixels = width * height

### finding ratio of diff_sum with respect to size of image
ratio = diff_sum/totalPixels

print("Ratio is: "+ratio)

if ratio>0.005:
    print("image is color")
else:
    print("image is greyscale")
```

Let's check out the [Lena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) image in color and grayscale:

Color Lena returns this:

```
Ratio is: 2.981109619140625
image is color
```

And Grayscale Lena returns this:

```
Ratio is: 0.0
image is greyscale
```

Comment: omg thank you so much! Yeah I was literally mixing Red Bull and Vodka... Thank you!!!