# least square line fitting in 4D space

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, curve-fitting

I have a set of points like:

(x , y , z , t)

(1 , 3 , 6 , 0.5)

(1.5 , 4 , 6.5 , 1)

(3.5 , 7 , 8 , 1.5)

(4 , 7.25 , 9 , 2)

I am looking to find the best linear fit on these points, let say a function like:
f(t) = a * x +b * y +c * z

Comment: Try to google for linear regression.

Comment: "f(t) = a * x +b * y +c * z": this is not a line equation; this is the explicit equation of a 3-hyperplane in 4D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the major axis of a point cloud.

You can work this out by finding the Eigenvector associated to the largest Eigenvalue of the covariance matrix. Could be an opportunity to use the [power method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) (starting the iterations with the point farthest from the centroid, for example).

Can also be addressed by [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), preferably using methods that compute the largest values only.

If your data set contains outliers, then RANSAC could be a better choice: take two points at random and compute the sum of distances to the line they define. Repeat a number of times and keep the best fit.

Using the squared distances will answer your request for least-squares, but non-squared distances will be more robust.

Comment: I am Using Singular Value decomposition.
Take a look here:

[Online Calculator](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/)

[fortran subroutine](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3691/dgesvd.html)

[C++ Code](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~dicook/JSS/paper/code/svd.c)

[Python COde](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298390/fitting-a-line-in-3d)

Answer (score 4):

This is [Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) problem. The "best fit" depends on the metric you define for being better.

One simple example is the [Least Squares Metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), which aims to minimize the sum of squares: `(f((x_i,y_i,z_i)) - w_i)^2` - where `w_i` is the measured value for the sample.

So, in least squares you are trying to minimize `SUM{(a*x_i+b*y_i+c*z^i - w_i)^2 | per each i }`. This function has a single global minimum at:

```
(a,b,c) = (X^T * X)^-1 * X^T * w

Where:
X is a 3xm matrix (m is the number of samples you have)
X^T - is the transposed of this matrix
w - is the measured results: `(w_1,w_2,...,w_m)`
The * operator represents matrix multiplication
```

There are more complex other methods, that use other distance metric, one example is the famous [SVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Regression) with a linear kernel.

Comment: In this way, we are going two find a line in 2D, a plane in 3D, and a hyperplane in 4D space, not a line.

Answer (score 1):

You have a linear problem.

For example, my equation will be Y=a*x1+b*x2+c*x3.

In MATLAB do it:

```
B = [x1(:) x2(:) x3(:)] \ Y;
Y_fit = [x1(:) x2(:) x3(:)] * B;
```

In PYTHON do it:

```
import numpy as np
B, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq([x1[:], x2[:], x3[:]], Y)
Y_fit = np.matmul([x1[:] x2[:] x3[:]], B)
```