# Fitting a straight line in 3D with errors on x,y,z

Tags: python, line, least-squares, data-fitting

I have a few spatial data points (x,y,z) with errors on all coordinates and I would like to fit a straight line to them. I struggle at finding the chi^2 to minimise. I found the 2D case [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190214161728/http://www.aip.de:80/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c15-3.pdf) (numerical recipies).[see also this pic for just the formula of the chi^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIyeg.png)

but I have troubles working it out in 3D - does anyone have experience/an idea?

Are there any python libraries that can deal with problems like this?

Comment: you might want to see this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298390/fitting-a-line-in-3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298390/fitting-a-line-in-3d)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have seen this post already though and it is not helpful, because the errors (sigma_x, sigma_y, sigma_z) of the points I want to fit do not take part in the fitting process (as it is the case for the chi^2 in the link I posted above).

Comment: If you have an equation system of type eg. 0=a*x+b*y+c*z+d you can simply use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq

Answer (score 0):

For the 2D case there is a paper: Krystek and Anton, Meas, Sci. Technol. **18** (2007) 3438-3442. I am sure that this can be generalized to 3D. The result would avoid an iterative process, but the details are probably quite cumbersome.

As an alternative an iterative solution may look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as m3d
import numpy as np
from random import random
from scipy.optimize import leastsq, fmin

def line_points( s, p, t ):
    return [ s * t[0] + p[0], s * t[1] + p[1], s * t[2] + p[2] ]

def weighted_dist( s, p, t, xVec, sigmaVec ):
    q = line_points( s, p, t )
    d  = ( q[0] - xVec[0] )**2 / sigmaVec[0]**2
    d += ( q[1] - xVec[1] )**2 / sigmaVec[1]**2
    d += ( q[2] - xVec[2] )**2 / sigmaVec[2]**2
    return np.sqrt( d )

def weighted_od( p, t, xVec, sigmaVec ):
    f = lambda s: weighted_dist( s, p, t, xVec, sigmaVec )
    sol = fmin( f, 0, disp=False )
    d = weighted_dist( sol[0], p, t, xVec, sigmaVec )
    return d

def residuals( params, data, sigmas ): ###data of type [ allx, ally, allz], sigma of type [allsx, allsy, allsz]
    px, py, pz, tx, ty, tz = params
    out = list()
    for x0, y0, z0, sx, sy, sz in zip( *( data + sigmas ) ):
        out += [weighted_od( [ py, py, pz ], [ tx, ty, tz ], [ x0, y0, z0 ], [ sx, sy, sz ] ) ]
    print sum(out)
    return out

myP = np.array( [ 1 , 1, 3 ] )
myT = np.array( [ -1 ,-3, .8 ] )
myT /= np.linalg.norm( myT )

sList = np.linspace( -3, 3, 100 )
lineList = [ line_points( s, myP, myT ) for s in sList] 
xData = [p[0] + .2 * ( 2 * random() - 1 ) for p in lineList ]
yData = [p[1] + .4 * ( 2 * random() - 1 ) for p in lineList ]
zData = [p[2] + .8 * ( 2 * random() - 1 ) for p in lineList ]

xyzData = [ xData, yData, zData ]
sssData = [ len(xData) * [.2], len(xData) * [.4], len(xData) * [.8] ]

residuals( [ 1, 1, 3, -1,-3,.8 ],  xyzData, sssData )
myFit, err = leastsq(residuals, [ 1, 1, 2 , -1, -2, -1 ], args=( xyzData, sssData ) )
print myFit

fitP = myFit[:3]
fitT = myFit[3:]
fitTN= np.linalg.norm( fitT )
fitT = [ fitT[0] / fitTN, fitT[1] / fitTN, fitT[2] / fitTN ]
fitLineList = [ line_points( s, fitP, fitT ) for s in sList ] 

ax = m3d.Axes3D(plt.figure() )
ax.plot( *zip(*lineList) )
ax.plot( *zip(*fitLineList) )
ax.scatter3D( xData, yData, zData )
plt.show()
```

Providing:

> > [  1.           1.00009764   2.98911266 121.35860193 364.44920212
> >      -92.27043484]

and

[image: data and fit]

The code surely can be made nicer. One could fit, e.g. theta and phi of the direction vector instead of the three components. A more careful handling of python lists and numpy arrays would help as well, I guess.

For errors and the cov matrix check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14854339/803359)