# Correlation coefficient of more than just two variables in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to find a correlation coefficient, or some equivalent measure, of more than 2 variables/columns of data? I have a large number of columns of data in Python, and I've found the correlation coefficient for all possible pairs of columns using np.corrcoef(), but I would like to somehow produce coefficients when relating 3 or more columns at once.

How I imagine this is I want to plot all the data points from 3 columns into a 3D space and find the vector that best fits the data, and how strongly linear the relationship is.

Comment: Look into PCA (principal component analysis). May not be exactly what you're looking for, but will give you a better understanding of the driving variables in your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about looking into PCA earlier. I'm just curious why there aren't any obvious ways to do this particular task. Only 2D correlation seems to be done.

Comment: This SO post may be useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2298390/8146556