# Fit a line to a set of points in 3D

Tags: python

I have a set of points in 3D (x, y and z over time). I use the `answer#1` in the following link to fit a line to the set of 3D points.

[Fitting a line in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298390/fitting-a-line-in-3d)

In the link above, the dimension of `data` (set of 3D points over time) is `(120,3)`. I can generate the `data`. In the code however, one can only visualize the results. How do I get for example `data_fit` of the same dimension as data but now the fitted one.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to get? An equation describing the line that has been fit?

Comment: yes. Either equation for 3 axis or directly an array "data_fitted".

Comment: What would your `data_fitted` array contain?

Comment: points that are fitted

Comment: More specifically, the blue line in the figure in the form of an array or equation.

Comment: The answer tells you how to do that: `linepts = vv[0] * np.mgrid[-7:7:2j][:, np.newaxis]` then anchor it to a point on the line (i.e. the mean): `linepts += datamean`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228639/discussion-between-lalu-and-ari-cooper-davis).

Comment: np.mgrid[-7:7:2j][:, np.newaxis] ... i didnt understand `7:7:2j`. Is there no way to get the fitted data as the same dimension as `data`?